# Create (automated) tests in qt creator for a library

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

I have created a project in QT Creator with qmake, that is a shared library. Now, for that library, I want to create some (automated) tests, that I can run, to assure that the code works, as it should.

I came across the `Google Test` package, which looks like what I could and should use.
However, I only found instructions for using it in `CMake` projects, which I don't use.

The project structure looks like this (As this is an example, the project is named `Example`):

```
Example/
----> src/
--------> Example.cpp
----> include/
--------> Example.hpp
--------> Example_global.hpp
----> tests/
--------> src/
------------> // Tests (Test files) should go here
```

Here are the contents of each file with their path:

Example/Example.pro:

```
# This is the .pro file for the project/library Example

QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += EXAMPLE_LIBRARY

CONFIG += c++20

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SRC_DIR     = $$PWD/src
HEADER_DIR  = $$PWD/include

INCLUDEPATH += $$SRC_DIR $$HEADER_DIR

SOURCES += \
    $$SRC_DIR/Example.cpp
    # Visual studio added the test files in here :/

HEADERS += \
    $$HEADER_DIR/Example_global.hpp \
    $$HEADER_DIR/Example.hpp

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Example/Example.pri:

```
# Later, if you want to use the library, you would include this .pri file

DEFINES += EXAMPLE_LIBRARY

SRC_DIR     = $$PWD/src
HEADER_DIR  = $$PWD/include

INCLUDEPATH += $$SRC_DIR $$HEADER_DIR
DEPENDPATH += $$SRC_DIR $$HEADER_DIR

SOURCES += \
    $$SRC_DIR/Example.cpp

HEADERS += \
    $$HEADER_DIR/Example_global.hpp \
    $$HEADER_DIR/Example.hpp
```

Example/src/Example.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Example.hpp"

EXAMPLE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

Example::Example()
{
}

EXAMPLE_END_NAMESPACE
```

Example/src/include/Example.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "Example_global.hpp"

EXAMPLE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class EXAMPLE_EXPORT Example
{
public:
    Example();
};

EXAMPLE_END_NAMESPACE
```

Example/include/Example_global.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(EXAMPLE_LIBRARY)
#  define EXAMPLE_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define EXAMPLE_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#ifdef EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE

# define EXAMPLE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name) ::EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE::name
# define EXAMPLE_USE_NAMESPACE using namespace ::EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE;
# define EXAMPLE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE namespace EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE {
# define EXAMPLE_END_NAMESPACE }
# define EXAMPLE_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(name) \
    EXAMPLE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE class name; EXAMPLE_END_NAMESPACE \
    using EXAMPLE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name);

#else

# define EXAMPLE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name) ::name
# define EXAMPLE_USE_NAMESPACE
# define EXAMPLE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
# define EXAMPLE_END_NAMESPACE
# define EXAMPLE_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(name) class name;

#endif // EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE
```

Example/tests/src/testExample:

```cpp
// Here, I would want to do something like this:

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

How can I write those test, and especially, how would I run them in QT Creator? Where would I tell QT that I want to add the `Google Test` package/library?

What I tried, was using Visual Studio and a plugin called `Qt Visual Studio Tools`, to import my QT Project into VS. Then, I installed the NuGet package `Google Test`. I was able to create tests, but the issue there was, that VS added all the test files (file paths) into my `Example.pro` files' `SOURCES` list.

AFAIK, this would include all the test files into my `Example` library, when I build it, which I don't think is a good idea.

So, is there a "better" way of doing this? Should I use CMake and add some `CMakeLists.txt` files? And if so, where should they go and what should they contain?

Thanks for any help!

(I should also say, that I am quite a noob with CMake and also a noob with creating libraries in c++)

Comment: Personally I use only `CMake` for QT projects, looks much more straightforward to me, but still it's a matter of preference. BTW code from your gist needs to be included directly in the question.

Comment: @pptaszni I would be fine with switching over to `CMake`. But as said, I don't really know what the `CMakeList.txt` files should contain then :/ (For example, how I should include `Google test`, where I should put its definition, and so on...)

Comment: I have used CMake for my Qt projects in Visual Studio since 2008. To get up to speed with CMake you will have to spend a few days working with example projects. I started out testing examples on the wiki pages for kitware.

Comment: For Google Test there is a quickstart here: [https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did now, was this:

First, I made a new `subdirs` project in QT Creator, which I just also called `Example` (for simplicity here, I will call it `Example_Base`). Then, I added my library project `Example` as a sub project. But instead of making it a shared library, this time I made it  a static library (basically I removed the `DEFINES += EXAMPLE_LIBRARY` and added `CONFIG += staticlib`).

Now, I added a `Auto Test Project` as another subproject, which I just called `Tests`. There, as a test framework, I chose `Google Test`. I then right-clicked on this `Tests` project and clicked on `Add Library -> Internal` where I then selected my `Example` project. This added my `Example` library into the `Tests` library, so that I can use everything from `Example` inside the `Tests` testing project.

All I have to do now, is to right-click on the `Example` project and hit `Build "Example"`.

Now, inside the `Tests` subproject, I can write some tests and run them by just clicking the "Play" icon in the bottom left corner inside QT Creator.

Also, my project structure looks like this now:

```
Example_Base/
----> Example/
--------> src/
------------> Example.cpp
--------> include/
------------> Example.hpp
--------> Example.pro
----> Tests/
--------> src/
------------> Test1.cpp
------------> TestX.cpp
------------> main.cpp
--------> Tests.pro
----> Example_Base.pro
```

(`Tests/src/main.cpp` just runs all the tests)

(Also note, that I am still using `qmake` instead of `CMake`)

**EDIT**

`Example_Base.pro` looked like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    WebSocket \
    Tests
```

By appending `CONFIG += ordered` at the end, I can directly click on the "Play" Icon without explicitely right-clicking on `Example` and hitting `Build "Example"`!